# My E2E tests on my webapi/signalr app run successfully individually but not if batched

Tags: c#, entity-framework, owin, xunit.net

If it matters I'm using:

- **xUnit** for the test runner
- **C# 4.5.1** (so that I can take advantage of `TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled` and just rollback a transaction across threads - `[AutoRollback]` didn't work)
- **Protractor.NET** for the browser/driver (the client uses Angular)
- **Owin** to self-host the site (if that's the right term)
- **EntityFramework** to set up the test data before each test and in my app to do most data access

When I run each test individually by right-clicking it, everything works fine.  However whenever I run them all using the Test Runner/Test Explorer all but the first throw exceptions.

I'm following the Arrange-Act-Assert pattern.  During "Arrange" I call `DbContext.SaveChanges()`.  That's when this error is thrown:

```
Result Message: 
System.Exception : The underlying provider failed on Open.
---- System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException : The underlying provider failed on Open.
-------- System.Transactions.TransactionException : The operation is not valid for the state of the transaction.
------------ System.Transactions.TransactionPromotionException : Failure while attempting to promote transaction.
---------------- System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException : There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.
-------------------- System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception : The wait operation timed out
```

I've tried googling several of the errors.  Enabling MARS in my connection string didn't fix it.  Extending the Timeout in my connection string didn't fix it.

I figured: maybe someone knows something about this pattern of nested exceptions and could shed some light on a precise issue.

If not, what are my next diagnostic steps to figure out why the exception is being thrown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was explicitly creating a `SqlConnection`/`SqlDataAdapter` in a WebApi endpoint of my code that creates a SQL query dynamically that tests 2 and 3 were calling and test 1 wasn't.  The outermost rollback transaction I described in my question along with the `SqlConnection` were causing the `connection.Open()` call in the WebApi endpoint to promote to being handled by the DTC.

I discovered this by putting this in my bootstrap code:

```
TransactionManager.DistributedTransactionStarted += TransactionManager_DistributedTransactionStarted;

// ...

void TransactionManager_DistributedTransactionStarted(object sender, TransactionEventArgs e)
{
    throw new Exception("DistributedTransactionStarted");
}
```

For the time being (I'll only do the following during these E2E tests ultimately) I rewrote my Ninject code to use singletons for `SqlConnection`s and made it so the `DbContext` does not own the connection.  This solved the exception I was getting above so therefore answers the question (even though I'm getting a different error now).  (I think I also ended up putting MARS back in my connection string, but that may have been for a different exception - can't remember.)